# Tabulator sorting data by default

Tags: tabulator

I am working on the exercise in the documentation. I would like the date to be sorted (asc) by default when data is first loaded into the table. 
In other words : when the user load the table, I would like him/her to see the youngest on top of the table (sorting by Date of Birth). 
I have read all the documentation but didn't find the clue. I tried `initialSort` as well  but wasn't able to fix it.

Any help ? Thanks you for your time

Comment: please post a link to a JS fiddle that shows how your table and data are setup. it is hard to offer the correct advice without knowing how things work your end

Answer (score 8):

`initialSort` should work. Have you included the moment.js library, as [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/sort#func-builtin) says?

In this example from my code, it works:

```js
    const dateFormatter = {
        inputFormat:"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        outputFormat:"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss",
        invalidPlaceholder:"(invalid date)",
    }

    var myTable = new Tabulator("#table", {
        columns:[ 
            {title:"Date", field: DATE_KEY, formatter:"datetime", formatterParams: dateFormatter },
            {title:"Total cases", field: CASES_KEY},
        ],
        initialSort:[
            {column:DATE_KEY, dir:"desc"}, //sort by this first
        ]
    });
```